# Combining python pivot tables

Tags: python, pivot-table

I would like to have a dataframe, created by combine only the total row values on two pivot tables and keeping the same column names, including the All column.

```
testA:
             sum                           
        ALL_APPS                           
MONTH        2012/08  2012/09  2012/10  All
DESCRIPTION                                    
A1            111      112      113     336
A2            121      122      123     366
A3            131      132      133     396
All           363      366      369    1098

testA:
             sum                           
        ALL_APPS                           
MONTH        2012/08  2012/09  2012/10  All
DESCRIPTION                                    
A1            211      212      213     636
A2            221      222      223     666
A3            231      232      233     696
All           663      666      669    1998
```

As I result I would like to have a data frame that would look like:

```
         2019/08  2019/09  2019/10  All
         363      366      369      1098
         663      666      669      1998
```

I tried:

```
A=testA.iloc[3]
B=testB.iloc[3]
my_series = pd.concat([A,B],axis=1)
```

But it does not do what I expected :(

```
                         All        All
              MONTH                        
sum ALL_APPS 2019/08  363.0        NaN
             2019/09  366.0        NaN
             2019/10  369.0        NaN
             All      1098.0       NaN
    CUR_VER  2019/08    NaN       663.0
             2019/09    NaN       666.0
             2019/10    NaN       669.0
             All        NaN       1998.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
my_series=pd.concat([testA.iloc[-1], testB.iloc[-1]], axis=1, ignore_index=True).T

my_series.columns=map(lambda x: x[3], testA.columns)
```

Comment: Thank you. The output has NaN values and again more columns than needed:  sum                                                                       ALL_APPS                                     CUR_VER                                 
MONTH    2019/08   2019/09   2019/10   All        2019/08  2019/09   2019/10   All
All             363.0       366.0       369.0    1098.0    NaN        NaN         NaN        NaN
All             NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN       663.0      666.0       669.0      1998.0

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to provide you with the result, but couldn't do the formatting right. The problem is with the NaN values, this code like mine behaves like outer join. I will edit the question so you can see what I mean. Thank you!

Comment: Ou, now I see - can you share output of: ```testA.columns``` and ```testB.columns``` - you have different columns in both dataframes (at least it looks like that)

Comment: Both pivot tables have '2012/08', '2012/09', '2012/10' and 'All' for columns. The outputs are above in the question.

Comment: So the result of ```testA.columns``` you're getting is list with these 4 strings? It does look like multiindex tbh

Comment: You are absolutely right. `testA.columns` results in  `MultiIndex(levels=[['sum'],['ALL_APPS'], ['2019/08', '2019/09', '2019/10', 'All']],labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]], names=[None, None, 'MONTH'])`

Comment: No worries- glad it worked:) I added some lines - to handle it within ```pd.concat```